# /home/jdoe doesn't appear after creating user named "jdoe"

Tags: user-management, administration, adduser

I'm running the last version of Ubunutu on VirtualBox. Just learning the usermod command. I got a problem :

when i type `sudo useradd -d /home/jdoe jdoe`
or `sudo useradd -D /home/jdoe jdoe`
or even `sudo useradd -b /home/jdoe jdoe`

my jdoe is sucessfuly created but i can't see his directory in the /home sectio. And when i logg as jdoe, i'm in the /home dir, i can see my personnal dir, but i can't see the jdoe one.

I don't find any solutions. I give you some pictures of the /etc/passwd file, and the user "back" is my personnal account.

Thanks for helping ! Here are some pics : https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhJ0d.jpg

Answer (score 2):

As noted in `man useradd`

```
   -d, --home-dir HOME_DIR
       The new user will be created using HOME_DIR as the value for the
       user's login directory. The default is to append the LOGIN name to
       BASE_DIR and use that as the login directory name. The directory
       HOME_DIR does not have to exist but will not be created if it is
       missing.
```

If you want `useradd` to create the directory, you need the `-m` or `--create-home` option, or set the `CREATE_HOME` value in `/etc/default/useradd`:

```
   -m, --create-home
       Create the user's home directory if it does not exist. The files
       and directories contained in the skeleton directory (which can be
       defined with the -k option) will be copied to the home directory.

       By default, if this option is not specified and CREATE_HOME is not
       enabled, no home directories are created.
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot !